# Proving that every symmetric matrix is similar to a symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, similar-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

If we consider $A$ to be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, then how can we show that there exists a unitary matrix $G$ such that :
$$
A=GTG^{*}
$$
where $T$ is a tridiagonal symmetric matrix.

I am not seeking a full answer but I am having a trouble understanding what this question is trying to tell me and how to start.

I know that for any matrix $A$, it can be decomposed via the Schur decomposition to two unitary matrices and an upper triangular matrix. I am not sure how I can see that symmetry here leads to the modification of the Schur decomposition so that $A$ becomes similar to a tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: I was wrong about my previous comment. This question is probably asking about [Lanczos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm), but I think you should make sure that the setting of your question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that for any matrix $A$, it can be decomposed via the Schur decomposition to two unitary matrices and an upper triangular matrix.

No, actually, the [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) tells you that for any matrix $A$, there exists a unitary matrix $Q$ and an upper triangular matrix $T$ such that

$$A=QAQ^{-1}$$

Since $Q$ is unitary, $Q^{-1}=Q^*$, so your question is literally just a rephrasing of the Schur decomposition.

Comment: Ah I see but from this concept, how can $A$ being symmetric be similar to a tridiagonal and not an upper triangular matrix via Schur decomposition?

Comment: @Альбина Schur decomposition of $A$, if $A$ is symmetric, is also symmetric, which means $T$ is, in that case, not only tridiagonal but *diagonal*.

Comment: @Альбина Note that another form exists, called the Hessenberg form of a matrix. Unlike the Schur form which is calculated iteratively, the Hessenberg form of any matrix can be found directly in a finite number of steps. Also, the Hessenberg form of a symmetric matrix is tridiagonal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix

Comment: @5xum You're right, that was a silly comment in retrospect. Of course, the proof uses the eigenvalues of the transformation (which of course "exist"), but these eigenvalues cannot be finitely calculated.

Comment: Hello again, I understand from your comments that any symmetric matrix can be converted to a tri-diagonal matrix via Householder transformation but this still does not address my main question. That is how should I begin proving the theorem aforementioned. I would hope for your assistance.

Comment: @Альбина What theorem? I thought your main question is precisely if a symmetric matrix can be converted into a tridiagonal matrix?